# Make multiple copies of one file with different names

Tags: bash, cp

How can I create multiple file from one?
Like, I have `1.json`, but want to create `2.json` + `3.json` + `4.json` out of it.

Most obvious way is to just `cp 1.json 2.json` and so on; but does Linux provide some way to do it in one command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
for i in {2..4} ; do cp 1.json "$i".json ; done
```

You can also use `tee`:

```
cat 1.json | tee {2,3}.json > 4.json
```

Instead of using the braces, you can just list the names, too:

```
for i in 2 3 4 ; do cp 1.json "$i".json ; done
cat 1.json | tee 2.json 3.json > 4.json
```

Comment: What if filenames should be some specific names: "one", "two" and so on?

Comment: @E1dar: You can use `for i in {two,three,four}.json` etc.

Comment: Thanks. This is how my final script looked like: `for i in one two three ; do cp projects/1.json projects/"$i".json ; done`

Comment: Note in general `tee` may be better than `cp`, because the source file is read just once, and it may be a large file. But if the filesystem supports CoW and your `cp` uses `--reflink=auto` by default, then `cp` may be way better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider hardlinks to the original file; the quickest copy you can make. Each copy also "copies" any changes you do to the original.

---

```
$ mkdir z
$ cd z
$ ls
$ echo >1 "Content of file 1"
$ ln 1 2
$ cat 2
Content of file 1
$ ln 1 3
$ ls -lh
total 12K
-rw-rw-r-- 3 hannu hannu 18 jun 15 22:34 1
-rw-rw-r-- 3 hannu hannu 18 jun 15 22:34 2
-rw-rw-r-- 3 hannu hannu 18 jun 15 22:34 3
$ cat 3
Content of file 1
$ echo >>2 "Content of file 2"
$ cat 1 2 3
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
$ echo >>3 "Content of file 3"
$ cat 1
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 3
$ rm 1
$ cat 3
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 3
$ cat 2
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 3
$ rm 2
$ cat 3
Content of file 1
Content of file 2
Content of file 3
$ rm 3
$ ls -lA
total 0
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf z
$
```

More info: `$ man ln` and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link